# How to send private message to FB friend with Chat API decprecated

Tags: facebook, api, deprecated, message

There is no proper FB API that I have found to send messages from my app. User authenticates using FB oAuth and selects a friend before writing a message in my app. I thought this should have been easy thing to do. First we tried using facebook email which is not supported anymore. THen we used chat api which now says as per v 2.0 is deprecated. 
Is there any other way to send facebook messages without using fb dialog box?
thanks,
Shez

Answer (score 2):

The very best way to send a message to a friend is to use the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

There is no other way with the API as of now.

Comment: Is there a way to pre-fill the message? This API call lets you send a message, but without being able to specify the message automatically, I can't see how this is any better than just manually sending a message the usual way.

Comment: prefilling is not allowed according to the platform policy.